# Form for Telerik RadRibbonBar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formborderstyle, telerik-radribbonbar

I got the Telerik RadRibbonBar for free with the Express edition of vb a while back, but it did not come with any sort of form. It also, unfortunately, has the control buttons there automatically. How would I create a form which is resizable, and works like a standard winform, but doesn't have the top bar?

I tried:

- FormBorderStyle = Sizable
- Text = Nothing
- ControlBox = False

Unfortunately, when you maximize the window, it goes in front of the taskbar...and it has an ugly border when it isn't maximized.

How can I:

1. Change border color?
2. Make it so it does not go in front of the taskbar?

Thanks for the help! I'm surprised there is not some sort of form already made for this.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik comes with a "Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadRibbonForm"
You have to add a RadRibbonForm Instead of a Standar Form.

Comment: Apparently the free version does not.